# Lower bound of merging k sorted arrays of size n

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, time-complexity, lower-bound

As the title suggests, I am wondering what the proof for the lower bound of merging k sorted arrays of size n is? I know that the bound is O(kn*log[k]), but how was this achieved? I tried comparing to sorting an array of p elements using a decision tree but I don't see how to implement this proof.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much easy to prove, try to think about it in a merge-sort way.
 To merge-sort an array of size **K*N** it takes **O(KN*log(K*N))**.

But we don't have to reach **leafs** of size **1**, as we know when the array size is **N** it is sorted. For simplicity we will assume **K** is a power of 2.
How many times do we have to divide by 2 to reach leafs of size N ?

**K** times!

**Visualization**
[image]

So you have **log(k)** steps, then having to merge each step costs **K*N***, and there are **log(k)** steps. Hence, the time complexity is **O(NK(log(K))**

**Proof:** 
Lets assume it is not a lower bound and we could achieve better. Then for any unknown array of size **N*K** we could split it in 2 until we reach sub-arrays of size **N**, merge-sort each of the arrays of size N in **Nlog(N)** time and in total for all the arrays **K*N*log(N)** time.

After having the K arrays of size N sorted, we have to merge them into a bigger array of size **N*K**, pay less than **O(NK*(log(K))** as we assumed it is not the lower bound.

At the end you sorted an unknown array of size N*K in a complexity lesser than **N*K*log(N*K)** which is not possible in the comparison model.

Hence, you can't achieve better than **O(NK*(log(K))** while merging the K sorted arrays of size N.

Answer (score 1):

Possible implementation.
Let's create a [heap data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) that store pairs `(element, arrayIndex)` ordered by element. Then

1. Add the first element of each array with the corresponding array index to this heap.
2. On each step, remove the top (lowest) pair `p` from the heap, add `p.element` to the result, and insert to the heap the pair `(next, p.arrayIndex)` with the next element from the array with `p.arrayIndex` index (if it is not empty).

For tracking 'next' element you need an array with `k` indices/pointers/iterators that are pointing to the next element of the corresponding array.

There will be at most `k` elements in the heap at any time, thus the `insert`/`remove` operations of the heap will have `O(log(k))` complexity. Every element will be inserted and removed once from the heap. The number of elements is `n*k`. Overall complexity is `O(n*k*log(k))`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a min heap of size k which stores the next item from each of the k arrays. Each node also stores which array it came from. Create your sorted array by adding the min from the heap to final_sorted_array, then adding the next element from the array that value came from to the heap.

Removing the min elt of the heap is O(log k). You have a total of NK elements so you do this NK times. Final result: O(NK log k).